# Creating an image array with images from the assets folder?

Tags: android, arrays, image

[image: This is my assets folder, the AICar images are the images I want to place in an array]

[[image: This is the method I've been using to individually store id's, but I think a for loop would be more efficient.[2]]

Most of the searches I've done show solutions for creating an array with images in the drawable folder, I want to use the assets folder but I haven't been able to create an array successfully. I'm sure I'm just make a small mistake, but I'm completely stuck. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but an easy way to do it would be

```
List<Bitmap> mBitmapArray  = new ArrayList<>();
mBitmapArray.add(gameScreen.getGame().getAssetManager().getBitmap(Asteroid1));
mBitmapArray.add(gameScreen.getGame().getAssetManager().getBitmap(Asteroid2));
mBitmapArray.add(gameScreen.getGame().getAssetManager().getBitmap(Asteroid3));
```

This would be creating a list as opposed to an array, but I figured that part was irrelevant. Obviously you could do the same idea with an Array.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Nic. I tried your method and I'm getting an error "Diamond types are not supported at this level". Any idea what that means?

Comment: Ah, looks like it's not happy about the Diamond Operator (http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074080/core-java/jdk-7--the-diamond-operator.html)  two solutions:

1.  List<Bitmap> mBitmapArray  = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
2. Make sure you're using Java 7 as your compiler and that your build tools are up to date

Comment: Make sure to mark the answer as correct if it worked for you.